# Find any particular day of the month with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to build in a calendar system into my app. The problem I'm currently on is once a month schedule. Basically if a person schedules on the second Wednesday of the month I want to automatically update the schedule to the second Wednesday of the next month. I've tried just adding `+ 1.month` but that doesn't achieve exactly what I want. Because it moves it to the next month date not day of the week. Does anyone know how I can achieve this. Here is what I'm currently doing that is not right.

```
def call
    schedule.update!(
      end_at: end_at_next_month,
      start_at: start_at_next_month,
      status: "monthly",
      arranged: true
    )
  end

  private

  def schedule
    context.schedule
  end

  def end_at_next_month
    schedule.end_at + 1.month
  end

  def start_at_next_month
    schedule.start_at + 1.month
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
DAYS_MAPPING = { 0=>"Sunday",
  1=>"Monday",
  2=>"Tuesday",
  3=>"Wednesday",
  4=>"Thursday",
  5=>"Friday",
  6=>"Saturday" }


# Returns week of month in integer
#   for example: 1 for matching day of 1st week of the month
def get_week_number(date)
  week_number = date.strftime('%U').to_i - date.beginning_of_month.strftime('%U').to_i
  offset = (Date.parse(DAYS_MAPPING[date.wday]) < date.beginning_of_month) ? 0 : 1

  week_number + offset
end

def specific_day_of_next_month(schedule)
  # wday => day of week in integer
  #   for example: 0 for Sunday; 1 for Monday & so on ...
  wday = schedule.wday
  week_number = get_week_number(schedule)

  next_month = schedule + 1.month
  days = (next_month.beginning_of_month..next_month.end_of_month).select { |d| d.wday == wday }
  days[week_number-1]
end
```

**Example 1:**

```
schedule = Date.today
# => Sat, 01 Jul 2017 (First Saturday of July)

specific_day_of_next_month(schedule)
# => Sat, 05 Aug 2017 (First Saturday of August)
```

**Example 2:**

```
schedule = Date.new(2017, 7, 10)
# => Mon, 10 Jul 2017 (Second Monday of July)

specific_day_of_next_month(schedule)
# => Mon, 14 Aug 2017 (Second Monday of August)
```

Comment: @Bitwise Sorry mate. But my solution was giving incorrect result in some cases. For example `specific_day_of_next_month(Date.new(2017, 7, 10))`. Just updated the answer, `get_week_number(date)` method.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But I'm getting this error now.`uninitialized constant NextMonthifyAssignment::DAYS` Any idea what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: I guess a better way to ask it is. What is the DAYS constant trying to do?

Comment: @Bitwise Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'

def date_of_nth_wday(month, year, wday, nth)
  base_date = Date.new(year, month)
  base_wday = base_date.wday
  ret_date = base_date +
             ( wday > base_wday ? wday - base_wday : 7 - base_wday + wday) +
             7*(nth-1)
  ret_date.month == month ? ret_date : nil
end
```

Obtain the date of the second Sunday of August, 2017

```
date_of_nth_wday(8, 2017, 0, 2)
  #=> #<Date: 2017-08-13 ((2457979j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Obtain the date of the third Friday of August, 2017

```
date_of_nth_wday(8, 2017, 5, 3)
  #=> #<Date: 2017-08-18 ((2457984j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Obtain the date of the fifth Monday of August, 2017

```
date_of_nth_wday(8, 2017, 1, 5)
  #=> nil (there are only 4 Mondays in August, 2017)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title is different to your explanation in the text. With my example you don't get the last friday, but you could select the 1,2,3,4,5th wednesday (or any other day) of a month.

```
require 'date'
class Date

  #~ class DateError < ArgumentError; end

  #Get the third monday in march 2008: new_by_mday( 2008, 3, 1, 3)
  #
  #Based on http://forum.ruby-portal.de/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=6157
  def self.new_by_mday(year, month, weekday, nr)

    raise( ArgumentError, "No number for weekday/nr") unless weekday.respond_to?(:between?) and nr.respond_to?(:between?)
    raise( ArgumentError, "Number not in Range 1..5: #{nr}") unless nr.between?(1,5)
    raise( ArgumentError,  "Weekday not between 0 (Sunday)and 6 (Saturday): #{nr}") unless weekday.between?(0,6)

    day =  (weekday-Date.new(year, month, 1).wday)%7 + (nr-1)*7 + 1

    if nr == 5
      lastday = (Date.new(year, (month)%12+1, 1)-1).day # each december has the same no. of days
      raise "There are not 5 weekdays with number #{weekday} in month #{month}" if day > lastday
    end

  Date.new(year, month, day)
  end
end

#2nd monday (weekday 1) in july
p Date.new_by_mday(2017,7,1,2)
```

If you look for a gem: [date_tools](https://rubygems.org/gems/date_tools) supports ths function.